# Program type already present: org.apache.xmlbeans.Filer

Tags: android, apache-poi

I am having problems to use Poi to read docx file to convert it to pdf in Android. In my gradle I have:

1. implementation files('libs\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar')
2. implementation files('libs\poi-ooxml-3.9.jar')
3. implementation files('libs\poi-3.9.jar')
4. implementation files('libs\xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar')

By removing this one

- implementation files('libs\xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar')

my issue is this one.

- NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/Color;

also using apachi poi latest version this error comes.

- MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Why are you using such old versions? What happens when you upgrade to the latest supported version?

Comment: same duplicate class found error on them.